# PHP form not doing anything

Tags: php, html

I am learning PHP for the first time. I am only trying to output a string to the page once the form has been submitted, but unfortunately, Nothing happens when form is submitted. There doesnt seem to be any errors. Pls what could be wrong?

```
<?php if(isset($_POST["submit"])){echo "it is done";} ?>




<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <form action="users.php" method="POST">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="username">username</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password"  name="password" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The HTML page writes over and hides the "it is done", try adding `exit()`  or `else {` ...html .... `<?php  }`

Comment: @DaveS — No it doesn’t.  “it is done” should be visible at the very start of the page.

Comment: Hmm, I've had HTML hide plain text output before but I'll assume you're correct here.  Then the action might be sending the user to a different page?  But that should generate a 404 if this isn't "users.php"

Comment: it still does not work, and the action is supposed to send to users.php.

Comment: @DaveS  I have also put in a non existing file in the action. i still dont get a 404 error. Nothing. The page just reloads, but i can see from the url query that form was submitted

Comment: Open f12 in your browser.  what navigations show in the network tab?

Comment: Unchecked runtime.lastError: A listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel closed before a response was received

Comment: That's a console error (although probably not relevant). That isn't what you were asked to check. Read the comment again.

Comment: `the action is supposed to send to users.php`...ok, and what actually happens? Does the URL change in the browser bar? What happens in the Network tool - do you see the POST request to users.php? Do you see any other requests at that time too? This is the kind of debugging info which might lead us towards an answer. The code by itself is not enough info, unfortunately.

Comment: If the script you provided is not users.php, then your check for the submit button in the $_POST will never be true.  The post goes directly to the target script.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
<?php
$message = '';
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    $message = 'It is done';
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <form action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="username">username</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php echo $message ?>
</body>

</html>
```

This will add "It is done" after the form.
If you want the page to just show "It is done" use the following.

```
<?php
$message = '';
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    $message = 'It is done';
    echo 'It is done';
} else {
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <form action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="username">username</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: ... and you have to assume that the file is called `users.php`. Checking for the existence of `$_POST['submit']` is already sufficient.